# I have code for image showing on scroll,but wheh i add another image that second image is not showing at all, any solution to this problem?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
 <!--This is code for showing picture on scroll-->
      


        var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        //IE Fallback
        function(callback){window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60)};

        var elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.show-on-scroll');

        function loop(){
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementsToShow,function(element){
            if (isElementInViewport(element)) {
              element.classList.add('is-visible')
            } else{
              element.classList.remove('is-visible')
            }
          });
          scroll(loop);
        }
        //Call the loop for the first time
        loop();

        //Helper function from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/274826
        function isElementInViewport(el){
          if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
            el=el[0];
          }
          var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
          return (
          (rect.top <=0
          && rect.bottom >=0)

          ||
          (rect.bottom >= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
          rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))

          ||
          (rect.top >= 0 &&
          rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
          );
        }

        const callback = function(entries) {
          entries.forEach(entry => {
            entry.target.classList.toggle('is-visible');
          });
        };

        const observer = new IntersectionObserver (callback);

        const targets = document.querySelectorAll(".show-on-scroll");
        targets.forEach(function(target){
          observer.observe(target);
        });
```

```css
/* Testing for fade in fade in animation */
.inline-photo{
  
  margin: 2em auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(4em) rotateZ(0deg);
  transition: transform 4s .25s cubic-bezier(0,1,.3,1),
  opacity .3s .25s ease-out;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 700px;
  width: 90%;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -70px;
}

.inline-photo.is-visible{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

```html
<p>This is paragraph</p>

<img src="https://zdnet4.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2018/03/16/c7559a57-f943-4875-ac83-eb65a870c9e7/semiinteriorcommand.jpg" class="inline-photo show-on-scroll" height="600px" width="1200px"> 

<img src="https://www.befunky.com/images/wp/wp-2014-08-milky-way-1023340_1280.jpg?auto=webp&format=jpg&width=1184" class="inline photo show-on-scroll" height="600px" width="1200px">
```

Comment: Please upload the code here in a working snippet, instead of an external link

Comment: https://codepen.io/webdeveloper-gif/full/RwGWVVK

Comment: i post it here can you acces it now ?

Comment: @FilipAligrudic, I have already posted your code here.

Comment: oh thank you i am new to stackoverflow so I didn't knew hot to post it like you did